# Failing to install gem Nokogiri-1.6.6.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am installing Nokogiri gem with `bundle install`, but its failing with below error in CentOS 6.6. I installed libxml2, libxslt also.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri-1.6.6.2.gem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160301-19713-3tkoho.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
        - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
        - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************

Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK
Running patch with /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/patch.log' to see what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib64
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:279:in `block in execute': Failed to complete patch task (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `chdir'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:271:in `execute'
        from extconf.rb:311:in `block in patch'
        from extconf.rb:308:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:308:in `patch'
        from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in `cook'
        from extconf.rb:278:in `block in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:177:in `tap'
        from extconf.rb:177:in `process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:475:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
[root@hh-rcs-push1 gemfiles]#
```

Comment: Very difficult to read your question with that kind of formatting. Have you tried to use the github version of nokogiri? Or at least to do what the log advises you to?

Comment: gem install nokogiri-1.6.6.2 failing in centos 6.6, but working with bundle install(when i placed nokogiri in Gemfile).

Comment: In the gemfile, try to replace with `gem 'nokogiri', github: 'sparklemotion/nokogiri'`

Comment: i did not get you answer. can you please explain with more details. 'gem install nokogiri-1.6.6.2' failing. bundle install working.

Comment: i am not using rvm. installed ruby rpm.

Comment: If you used an RPM, did you also install the ruby-dev bundle so you have the headers? In general we recommend installing using RVM or rbenv, which manage all this stuff for you nicely. In my experience, installing a language, Ruby, Perl, Python, using RPM results in the language being installed but nothing necessary for adding gems/modules/libraries with native drivers.

Comment: Have you tried a new version? Perhaps the gem that depends on nokigiri will pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with installing rvm(ruby version manager).